# TextBoxes and enabling buttons

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program where I have three textboxes and a calculate button, and I only want the calculate button to be enabled if there is a value in all three textboxes. This is the code I am using at the moment but the button stays enabled even if all three textboxes are empty

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FirstNumber = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    SecondNumber = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
    ThirdNumber = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    Result = (SecondNumber - FirstNumber) / ThirdNumber
    Label5.Text = Result
    If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" And TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End If
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: if your user types letters do you want the button enabled?

Comment: The user types numbers and I only want the button to be enabled if all three textboxes contain numbers

Comment: You should look at the Validating event of the 3 textboxes

Answer (score 1):

Just one event handler for all 3 textboxes.
In the event code you check the value of the textbox and set a boolean to enable or not the button

```
Private Sub textBoxes_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
               ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) _
               Handles textBox1.Validating, textBox2.Validating, textBox3.Validating

  Dim areValid As Boolean = True
  Dim intValue As Integer

  if Not Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, intValue) Then
      areValid = false
  else if Not Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, intValue) Then
      areValid = false
  else if Not Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, intValue) Then
      areValid = false
  End If
  Button1.Enable = areValid
  ' You could force the focus to remain on the invalid textbox enabling this line
  ' e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code for each textbox's text_changed event. The button does not know what is happening in the textboxes when text gets entered...

Hooking up toe the text_changed event, you will have to evaluate all 3 textboxes from all three textboxes' text changed events. Disable your button accordingly.

Comment: I have moved the if statement from the button each of the textbox's text changed events but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextChange events of all 3 text boxes on the TextBox1_TextChanged.
It will check if it only contains numbers."If not disable button again in the else"
Of course the button needs to be disabled at start.

And also i don't know if you want to have numbers like 1.2"Then use Double like in the code below"

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) = True And IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) = True And IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) = True Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Dim FirstNumber As Double
Dim SecondNumber As Double
Dim ThirdNumber As Double
Dim Result As Double

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FirstNumber = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
    SecondNumber = CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
    ThirdNumber = CDbl(TextBox3.Text)
    Result = (SecondNumber - FirstNumber) / ThirdNumber
    Label5.Text = Result
End Sub
```